# Update Nested Dictionary value by comparing it with existing list

Tags: python

How to make changes in nested dictionary value by comparing its key value with an existing list.

Eg.: I have list name as common:

```
common=['abc','def','xyz','etc']
mydict={'abc':{'a':10,'b':20,'c':10}, 'rat':{'r':10,'a':20,'t':10} , 'etc':{'e':10,'t':20,'c':50}}
```

Now I want to change the value of 'b' to 50 because it exists in mydict key value
same as I want to change the value of 't' to 10 
I don't want any changes in 'rat' because it does not exist in list common.

```
common=['abc','def','xyz','etc']

mydict={'abc':{'a':10,'b':20,'c':10}, 'rat':{'r':10,'a':20,'t':10} , 'etc':{'e':10,'t':20,'c':50}}
```

input:

```
common=['abc','def','xyz','etc']

mydict={'abc':{'a':10,'b':20,'c':10}, 'rat':{'r':10,'a':20,'t':10} , 'etc':{'e':10,'t':20,'c':50}}
```

expected output:

```
mynewdict={'abc':{'a':10,'b':'50,'c':10}, 'rat':{'r':10,'a':20,'t':10} , 'etc':{'e':10,'t':10,'c':50}}
```

Comment: How do you know the numbers to be the new ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexing into a nested dictionary and compare the values of its keys.

```
common=['abc','def','xyz','etc']
mydict={'abc':{'a':10,'b':20,'c':10}, 'rat':{'r':10,'a':20,'t':10} , 'etc':{'e':10,'t':20,'c':50}}

for items in mydict:
    if items in common:
        inneritem= mydict[items]
        if 'b' in inneritem:
            inneritem['b']=50
        if 't' in inneritem:
            inneritem['t']=10

print(mydict)
```

Comment: `{'abc': {'a': 10, 'b': 50, 'c': 10, 't': 10}, 'rat': {'r': 10, 'a': 20, 't': 10}, 'etc': {'e': 10, 't': 10, 'c': 50, 'b': 50}}`

Comment: Thanks @Lê Tư Thành, corrected the code to handle the case where 't' or 'b' is not present at the begininng

Comment: You can consider using `if 'b' in items:`  instead of the current. As I know, we should minimize calling the dictionary's element, it will help when you have a long script working with dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a comprehension for one update at a time.  Multiple updates would make this approach quite cumbersome unless you don't mind adding the "t" key to sub-dictionaries that don't have it.:

```
newdict={k:{**d,'t':10} if k in common and 't' in d else d for k,d in mydict.items()}
```